# sedutil-cli is not wiping SATA SSD with PSID

Tags: command-line-interface, erase, solid-state-drive

##### My goal is to erase all data from the SATA SSD by using sedutil-cli and PSID

If during sedutil-cli PSID erase the SSD is reverted back to factory settings then so be it.

I made sure to add `libata.allow_tpm=1` to extlinux boot options as Linux Mint 21 was being loaded.

Once the OS is loaded: I entered the following command into the terminal

> echo = "instead of XXXX a real PSID key was used that was printed on the back of the drive"
>
> sudo ./sedutil-cli --PSIDrevert XXXX /dev/sdX
>
> sudo ./sedutil-cli --yesIreallywanttoERASEALLmydatausingthePSID XXXX /dev/sdX

After the command was complete I physically removed the SATA Hot-Swappable SSD from the machine and waited until `disks` utility updated list of drives to show that drive was removed. Then I put the drive back in and waited for the `disks` utility to update again.

I was expecting the `disks` utility to show no partitions on the wiped drive because I am under the impression that if all data is erased using the PSID revert then partition table would be erased as well.

To my great surprise the drive in question had an *EXT4* partition called *asdf* **before** the sedutil-cli command **and after** the sedutil-cli command.

That tells me that **my data was NOT ERASED** because the partition is still there...

Here is a screenshot of what happened: **NOTE the *asdf* *EXT4* partition still present AFTER the PSID erase?!?!?!**
[image]

Side-note: I tried the exact same process as in the screenshot on an ancient mainboard with BIOS and not UEFI. The ancient mainboard had LSI HBA 9201-16e in JBOD mode (not RAID mode). I also tried the exact same process with a modern laptop with UEFI, (not BIOS). Because I tried the exact same process on two different mainboards I suspect it is NOT the hardware compatibility issue. Also Linux Mint is pretty good with drivers and hardware out of the box so I suspect it is not OS issue either.

##### Question: How do I permenantly wipe all data from the SATA SSD using the PSID and sedutil-cli command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

BEFORE issuing the "erase command" to the SSD, it is necessary to issue the "initial setup" command

```
sudo sedutil-cli --initialSetup TEMPPASSWORD /dev/sdX # Should be the first command
```